# React Testing Library: How to query element by component name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, components, react-testing-library

When I need to find the component to expect that display correctly like...

user_detail.tsx

```
...

return <div>
   {isTrue ? <Avatar /> : <Title> }
</div>
```

user_detail.spec.tsx

```
...

it('Should render Avatar when flag isTrue is true', () => {
  expect(screen.findByRole('Avatar')).not.toBeFalsy()
})
```

I always got an error `Unable to find an accessible element with the role "Avatar"`

Is there any solution to find elements by component name?

Comment: Avatar isn't a valid [ARIA role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques), it's not clear why you thought that might work. The Testing Library family encourages you to select by things that matter to end users, and the name of your component is absolutely **not** one of those. See https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-which-query/#priority for a guide to picking queries.